# Resolve function not working in Angularjs $dialogue service

Tags: angularjs

Folks I am using ui.bootstrap.dialog server to open a modal window with some data in it. In order to create the modal window I have the following code:

```
$scope.data = {"one" : "a","two" : "b"};

$scope.viewopts = {
 backdrop: true,
 keyboard: true,
 backdropClick: false,    
 templateUrl: 'templates/view-add-dialogue.tpl.html',    
 controller: 'ViewAddDialogController',
 resolve: {
        user: function(){
        return $scope.data;
        }
    }
};



$scope.addCustomView = function() {
console.log("addCustomView");
var d = $dialog.dialog($scope.viewopts);
d.open();

};
```

Later on I have defined a controller as below:

```
function VeiwAddDialogController($scope,dialog,user){
console.log(user);
$scope.close = function(result){
        dialog.close(result);
    };

 }
```

However the "user" object that gets passed to the controller does not have the data but instead prints the following to the console:

```
function (){
  return $scope.data;
}
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Where does the first code block actually live in your application?

Answer (score 0):

ok .. just using the following did the trick:

```
resolve: {
    headerlist: $scope.headers

 }
```

Thanks to those you replied.